# Strange sorceresses swallow scarlet swedes

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

What is interesting about this sentence?

> Strange sorceresses swallow scarlet swedes, see - snubbing saintliness.

HINT:

> [My first is in the kill zone, but not in no man's land](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/61639/5373)

Comment: Can you define "interesting"? I found a lot of things interesting!

Comment: @Saeïdryl There should be one thing which is particularly interesting, once you see it. But the [tag:enigmatic-puzzle] tag means I'm not telling you what sort of thing :-)

Comment: @Snow Google is trained on your search history. When I Google "scarlet swede", all I get is stuff about vegetables and Scandinavians.

Comment: I assume you mean something other than the alliteration, which I have always found amusing and interesting.

Comment: I think this may be a quote from a book / movie. We have to find it from the synonyms of the above words.

Comment: The interesting part is that someone with a lisp will hate you, if you make them speak this sentence.

Comment: @PL457 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AX0XDHF3M60

Comment: I agree that the words seem to be crying out for synonyms. I wondered about "weird witches ..." and "... red rutabagas, right? -- rebuffing righteousness", but I couldn't get all the initial sounds to match up.

Comment: Its an alliteration, but this is Puzzling SE not Literature SE unfortunately

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, perhaps "Exotic Enchantresses Eat ..."

Comment: Another interesting thing about the first sentence is that you can post anything below it and people will still be looking at the second sentence to find some logic. (I don't think this is a serious enough attempt to post as an actual answer.)

Comment: can we get another hint maybe?

Comment: @YeetKid Sure - I'll think about what hint to give next and maybe post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that ...

> ... the sentence can be rewritten with synonyms for each word so that the starting letters of the words correspond to the letters of the top row on an English keyboard in order:
>
>      **Q**ueer **w**itches **e**at **r**ed **t**urnips, **y**ou **u**nderstand — **i**gnorant **o**f **p**iety.
>
>  Here, "see" and "snubbing" are both replaced with two words. "Ignorant of" isn't really the same as snubbing; the ingoring is inadvertent for the former and deliberate for the latter. I tried to think of other words or expressions on the pattern of "i—ing on/of", but couldn't find anything useful. The rest seems to fit nicely, though.

Is there more to it?

> I also thought that the sentence could perhaps be rewritten to fit every line of the typewriter. The second row starts off promising with "Alien spellcasters devour ...", but then trickles out. The seven letters of the bottom row could be matched by coalescing two words of the original sentence, and there is a b for beetroot, which could mean red swedes (with a bit of biological licence), but it comes too late on the row.
>
>  So let's not overthink it. I'll go with my original answer.

Comment: You got it! :-D I had very slightly different words in mind for the last part; would you say "irrespective of" fits better than "ignorant of"? (Or "irregardless", if you want to drive grammar pedants insane.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, irrespective is better. Or perhaps irreverent?

Answer (score 5):

This might be a big stretch, but it (interestingly?) reminds me of

> Macbeth, by William Shakespeare

Because

> The (Strange sorceresses) **three witches** force Macbeth to **trust** (swallow) the (scarlet) **red** (swedes) **herrings** of their omens: They (see) **foretell** the future, like, totally (snubbing) **discrediting** his (saintliness) **morailty**.

Comment: Wow that's amazing

Comment: just shows what's possible with a big enough hammer,  if it was That  *spew* would be better than *swallow* and *salmon* better than *swedes*

Comment: Interesting find, but it doesn't quite work: in your interpretation, the sorceresses aren't doing the swallowing but making their dupe do so. Also, if this were the answer, then it wouldn't really be [tag:wordplay] - just an alliterative description of the events of a particular story.

Comment: Didn't think it really was the answer, but decided to add it as food for thought for others.

Answer (score 1):

Best I can do so far, along the lines of the puzzle in the hint, is

> Goofy hags ingest Jezebel's kohlrabis, lo -- mocking nobility

where

> successive words begin with successive letters of the alphabet

but several of the words aren't terribly convincing. I've also looked for similar sentences where

> all the words begin with the *same* letter, but despite some promising fragments (weird witches wolf ...; red rutabagas, right? -- rebuffing righteousness) I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: Good try, but this puzzle isn't *exactly* like the one mentioned in the hint. If it were, it would be boring! The hint is less direct, meaning only that the idea of this puzzle is similar to (but not the same as) the idea of the previous one.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, I wasn't assuming it *was* the same as the previous one. (As you know, my initial attempt was looking for things with the same first letter.) I have a few other half-baked ideas along similar lines but so far none has borne any more fruit than the ones already mentioned.

Comment: I hope the eventual correct answer will be worth it ...

Answer (score 1):

Partial guess. The words of the sentence...

> ...could be replaced by synonyms that each contain a single "i" and "e":
>
>  *Weird witches ingest reddish (swedes?), view - fending piety*
>
>  Not sure yet about "swedes". "See" could also be: cite, in re (regarding), glimpse, discern